# gunicorn - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I am attempting to create a docker image with flask, gunicorn, and nginx.
This application downloads a zip file generated with io.BytesIO() returning a send_file() function.

this is the function that generates the zip file:

```
def download_zip():
    result = decode_base64()

    zip_file_bytes_io = io.BytesIO()  # Create an in-memory zip file from the in-memory image file data.

    with ZipFile(zip_file_bytes_io, 'w') as zip_file:
        for image_name, bytes_stream in result:
            zip_file.writestr(str(image_name) + ".jpg", base64.decodebytes(bytes_stream))
    zip_file_bytes_io.seek(0)

    return zip_file_bytes_io
```

This is the Flask function that downloads the file:
@app.route('/download')

```
def download():
    zip_file = download_zip
    print("Zip File ready")
    # zip_file = None
    if not zip_file:
        return render_template("download.html")
    else:
        return send_file(zip_file, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='archive.zip')
```

The file downloads ok when I use the Flask native server in development:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=os.environ.get('DEBUG') == '1')
```

However, it returns **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read'** when I use the gunicorn server.

Here is the full error report:

```
[2022-07-20 06:12:11 +0000] [24] [ERROR] Error handling request /download
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 136, in handle
web_1    |     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 182, in handle_request
web_1    |     resp.write_file(respiter)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 386, in write_file
web_1    |     for item in respiter:
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 35, in __getitem__
web_1    |     data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
web_1    | AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'read'
proxy_1  | 192.168.128.1 - - [20/Jul/2022:06:12:11 +0000] "GET /download HTTP/1.1" 500 141 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parenthesis here:

```
zip_file = download_zip
```

it should be:

```
zip_file = download_zip()
```